Problema Transform Manim
estoy aprendiendo Manim, y estoy desarrollando un ejemplo en el que se tiene una función f(x), y la animación lo que intenta hacer es cambiar la x por una y, pero cuando uso transform, se reemplaza, pero queda desplaza un poco hacia la izquierda. No queda centrada como estaba antes con la x. ¿Cómo podría solucionar esto? ¡Gracias!

Después de que se usa transform pasa esto:

A pesar de que los paréntesis se abren lo hacen en la misma cantidad de espacio, por lo que el texto debería quedar centrado igual.
Aquí está el código:
class taller(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        self.camera.background_color=WHITE
        text1 = MathTex("f(","x",")",color=ORANGE).scale(5)
        text1.set_color_by_tex("x",BLACK)
        text3 = text1.save_state()
        text4 = Text(r"10 a.m.",color=BLACK,slant=ITALIC).scale(3)
        text2 = Text(r"y",color=BLACK,slant=ITALIC).scale(3)
        self.play(Write(text1))
        self.wait(1)
        self.play(text1[0].animate.shift(2.5*LEFT),text1[2].animate.shift(2.5*RIGHT),Transform(text1[1],text2))
        self.wait(1)
        self.play(Restore(text3))
        self.wait(1.5)
        self.play(text1[0].animate.shift(2.5*LEFT),text1[2].animate.shift(2.5*RIGHT),Transform(text1[1],text4))
        self.wait(1.5)


No tengo mucha experiencia con manim, pero puedes hacerlo cambiando tu segundo texto a un MathTex copiando exactamente el contenido del primero, excepto el segundo substring (el que quieres animar, la "y"):
class Taller(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        self.camera.background_color=WHITE
        
        text1 = MathTex("f(x)", substrings_to_isolate="x", color=ORANGE, font_size=90)
        text1.set_color_by_tex("x", BLACK)

        text2 = MathTex("f(y)", substrings_to_isolate="y", font_size=90)
        text2.match_style(text1)

        self.play(Write(text1))
        self.wait(1)

        self.play(
            text1[0].animate.shift(2.5 * LEFT),
            text1[2].animate.shift(2.5 * RIGHT),
            Transform(text1[1], text2[1])
            )
        self.wait(1)

        self.play(
            text1[0].animate.shift(2.5 * RIGHT),
            text1[2].animate.shift(2.5 * LEFT)
            )
        self.wait(1)


